# EXTJS: Drag n Drop between Grids causes data duplication..how to avoid that?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, grid

I have a Data grid panel g1 which holds master data, second grid g2 which is subset/user selections out of g1 grid.  Situation is like , if i select data from g1 to g2 and that row is already there , it allows n let it drag n drop between two grids .. just creating duplication/confusion for user . so kindly advice how to avoid this duplication of rows in the DND grid groups here ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is quite broad, can you provide some code or a fiddle?. You should probably override the onDrop method to get the record and check the store for existing records before completing the drop.

Comment: Thanks Scriptable, my initial problem is solved ..figured out the problem in model which caused the duplicatiton :)..  but now facing another issue due to this effect..my original datastore gets emptied after all drag n drop from source to target grid !! ..how to retain the source grid's store after the drop ?  maybe just shallow copy on dnd action ??

Comment: yes, copy the record from one store to another and then cancel the drop reqest

Comment: thanks ..but programmatically ,how to copy/cancel the drop between grids?  any config to be made?

Comment: See how I have achieved a similar feature [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h0u)

Comment: Thanks Sciptable...however my situation here is between 2 grids. Just was able to resolve it by :   copy:true in viewConfig and not in plugin config  like this -                                                                                                      viewConfig: {
         copy: true, // allows datastore to orginal after dnd from source.
                   plugins: {

Answer (score 0):

finally found out the exact config i need to use in datagrid view file:

**viewConfig**: {
            **copy: true**,                                                             plugins: { } }

this allows your source Datastore to retain n only copies the record to target on DND actions. Cheers!!